# Keras trains samples of different sizes at the same time. Is there a solution?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The one-dimensional neural network built by keras needs to use three lengths of audio as input at the same time. Is there any way to realize it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need models that handle 3d data `(batch_size, audio_length, audio_channels)`. Then if you make the model's input shape `(None, audio_channels)`, your model will accept any audio length. You must use layers like Conv1D and RNN layers, you cannot use `Flatten`, you will need to replace it for some global pooling.